# Can I get the failed test case names using robot.api?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to get the failed test case names from a output.xml using robot api in python, I am able to get the count for failed/passed tests using the below code but could not find any methods to get test case names.
Thanks in advance.

```
from robot.api import ExecutionResult

result = ExecutionResult('output.xml')
result.configure(stat_config={'suite_stat_level': 2,
                              'tag_stat_combine': 'tagANDanother'})
stats = result.statistics
print stats.total.critical.failed
print stats.total.critical.passed
print stats.tags.combined[0].total
```

Comment: Show content of output.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need `ResultVisitor`. Something like that should help:

```
from robot.api import ExecutionResult, ResultVisitor

class Visitor(ResultVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        self.failed = []

    def end_test(self, test):
        if test.status == "FAIL":
            self.failed.append(test)

visitor = Visitor()

result = ExecutionResult('output.xml')
result.visit(visitor)
print(visitor.failed)
```

Documentation could be found at https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.1.2/autodoc/robot.result.html#module-robot.result.visitor

Answer (score 0):

Using gatherfailed module from robot python module, you can have gather_failed_tests and gather_failed_suites functions to directly fetch failed tests and suites.
Which is kind of one line answer.

```py
from robot.conf.gatherfailed import gather_failed_tests, gather_failed_suites
print(gather_failed_suites("output.xml")
print(gather_failed_tests("output.xml")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?